# Issues with CSS overflow and display

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with 3 divs.

I have one that is container(`"position : absolute; z-index: -1"`), and the other two are sub containers(`"position : absolute; z-index: *n*"`) overplayed for the purpose of animation. Anyway the  two sub containers have a "grid" of spans(`"position: relative; display: inline-block"`). with fixed size 25x25 px and the spans have background image form sprite. he problem is that the overflow of the container does not seem to affect (i.e the spans that are supposed to be hidden are still showing, under it seems that it does not obey the "height" property of the element) the sub containers. Any ideas for a solution?

I do not have any other stylesheet , or in document styles, everything is generated on the go with JS & jQuery. will provide a screenshot after 8-10 hrs =D

The browser tested on is Latest FF(20.0) in Ubuntu

**EDIT**
Here is a fiddle [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D6Zzs/)

Comment: Can you try to make a jsfiddle?  It's hard to follow

Comment: Please include a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing the problem

Comment: fiddling in a second guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally issues with `display:inline` or `inline-block` elements come up as a result of the size of the text that would normally occupy them. The remedy to this is to play around with `line-height`. Since you won't have any text at all you can safety set it to `0`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/cQkAh/)

[image]

```
#layer1 {
    line-height:0;
}
```

I Tested it in Chrome 26 and Firefox 20.

Here is an alternate solution using `vertical-align:top` from CherryFlavourPez

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/4MUwc/)

```
#layer1 span {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

---

About the `overflow`. You're using `overflow:hidden` on `#map` where the structure is as so:

```
<div id="map">
    <div id="layer1">
    <div id="layer2">
</div>
```

This is all fine except for the fact that `#layer1` and `#layer2` are positioned absolutely which takes them out of the flow of the page. You can cut the bottom by applying `overflow:`hidden to the layers if you want, but not on #map.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/G8uuY/)

```
#layer1,
#layer2 {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: OK +1 for that but could you give me answer to the question above, about the overflow?

Comment: Rather than setting `line-height` to `0` (which may cause issues if the markup includes any text in the future), I'd recommend setting the `vertical-align` property to anything other than the default `baseline` (e.g. `span { vertical-align: top` }) will remove the gaps. Those gaps are there for descenders on letters like 'g' and 'p', hence why setting `line-height` will fix the issue.